# nv12 to rgb24 color misalignment issue

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, bgr, nv12-nv21

NV12 pixel format conversion to RGB24 issue

I use gpu decoding from ffmpeg. The AVFrames I get I have to converted to rgb24 (Bitmap). When I use sw_scale (nv12->bgr24) all colors are ok, but the left border show the following disterbunce.

[sw_scale conversion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hsufd.png)

Is this issue familiar to anyone? Anything for suggestion?

When I use custom conversion taken from project ["PixelFormatConverter"](https://github.com/Zaplatnikov/PixelFormatConverter/blob/master/PixelFormatConverter/PixelFormatConverter/PixelFormatConverter.cpp#L1394)

I get the following result (border distortion, and color misalignment):

[border distortion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbV8O.png)

[color misalignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bblm0.png)

Is these issues familiar to anyone? Anything for suggestion?

After the conversion I create the bitmap and display it. For Bitmap creation I use the following:

```cpp
frame is AVFrame (NV12) taken from FFMPEG
int image_size = av_image_get_buffer_size(AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24, frame->width, frame->height, 32);

size_t sizeof_file_header = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER);
size_t sizeof_info_header = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);

bmpheader.bfType = 0x4d42;
bmpheader.bfReserved1 = 0;
bmpheader.bfReserved2 = 0;
bmpheader.bfOffBits = sizeof_file_header + sizeof_info_header;
bmpheader.bfSize = bmpheader.bfOffBits + image_size;

bmpinfo.biSize = sizeof_info_header;
bmpinfo.biWidth = frame->width;
bmpinfo.biHeight = frame->height;
bmpinfo.biPlanes = 1;
bmpinfo.biBitCount = 24;
bmpinfo.biCompression = BI_RGB;
bmpinfo.biSizeImage = 0;
bmpinfo.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
bmpinfo.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
bmpinfo.biClrUsed = 0;
bmpinfo.biClrImportant = 0;

uint8_t* buffer = new uint8_t[bmpheader.bfSize];

memcpy(buffer, &bmpheader, sizeof_file_header);
memcpy(buffer + sizeof_file_header, &bmpinfo, sizeof_info_header);

NV12_TO_BGR24(frame->data[0], (buffer + (bmpheader.bfOffBits)), frame->width, frame->height);
```

Can anyone spot the issue?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, You see above from the code the buffer has the headers first copied.

Comment: I think this is an issue with stride. The actual AVFrame buffer linesize is always a multiple of 32, but the framewidth isn't. The shown artifacts (not that easy to tell without the original and full size images) at least look at lot like it. In order to test this theory, try to use a video with a width that is actually a multiple of **64** (64 because U and V planes are just half the size)

Comment: Thanks, this frame width is in fact1920 (30X64).

Comment: Mhh in that case, can you provide more code? Or dump the AVFrame NV12 buffer in some file and share it here

Comment: Crigges thanks for your help. In the following link you can download a bmp dump file produced by my code. If you see anything please let me know. As far as the code the above is the exact one that I use.      
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/dd00e024acda5f0b078acfb170c706b220231009174209/93ebd9?utm_campaign=TRN_TDL_05&utm_source=sendgrid&utm_medium=email&trk=TRN_TDL_05

Comment: This does not help, since my assumption is that the memory layout inside the AVFrame buffer causes this problem, so please dump the contents of `frame->data[0]` in a binary file. Also check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) about MVCEs, because as is nobody can help you because your example is not complete.